# Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp

Tags: java, class, classpath

I am pretty new to this but I seem to have a problem for a day now, and I can't get around it. Have looked over the other similar post but nothing worked. I just got the basic tutorial, made my Java file.

Used the `javac HelloWorldApp.java` command and got the class file.

But every time I try to run the `java -cp . HelloWorldApp` command, I get the `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp` error. Pretty sure I am doing something wrong, just don't know what. I am on a Windows 7 machine with jdk1.8.0_31.

Comment: If you are not using any external jars no need of -cp in java execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run your `.class` file with `java filename` command, provide you are running it from the `src` directory

Answer (score 0):

Your current working directory may not be in your classpath, before running java class issue this command to include PWD into your classpath :

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.
java yourAppName
```